# FileReader() is not defined in Angularjs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, angularjs-directive, gruntjs

I am working on file upload functionality on UI. Basically, on my UI page, I need to read file contents and display when the user selects local file from his/her machine. For this, I googled and I found this http://plnkr.co/edit/eeQbR65oE8iljm7ueGhX?p=preview  example. It is working fine. but I used in my application, its not working and giving me error that"FileReader" is not defined.

Here is my example:

```
function onReadFile($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);

            element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result});
                    });
                };

                reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: are you trying this IE9 then it will not work.. IE9 doesn't support `FileReader`

Comment: Have you tried this in your own plnkr?

Comment: Hi Jasen, Yes, I tried Plnkr one.Its working fine.I just copied same and exact thing into my application. It's giving me "FileReader" is not defined.

Comment: I mean, add your relevant code to your own plnkr. Since it works with the cited plnkr your browser supports `FileReader`. Now you'd need to narrow down the problem in your app. What's your full directive look like? How are you using it? Do you have any other properties named "FileReader" or something very similar?

Comment: angular.module('systemsManagement.assetcommandcenter').directive('fileReader',fileReader);

Comment: var reader = new FileReader(); giving me an error saying that 'FileReader' is not defined. please help me. thanks